# Include a jar from within another jar in the classpath for a transitive dependency

Tags: java, maven

I know its very unusual and wrong but there is a reason for this thats not relevant for the story, for now we cant avoid it.

Im using Maven and have jar A that uses jar B, I copied jar B into the `resources` folder of jar A and included jar B in the POM file of jar A with `provided` scope, an example:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Lists.asList("foo", new String[] {"bar"}));
    }
}
```

POM:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>[15.0]</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now I have jar C that uses jar A like so:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.main(null);
    }
}
```

I tried doing this in the POM of C:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ex</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But it doesnt work because it cant find the guava classes, so my question is, is it possible to somehow make this work and added jar B to the classpath from within jar A?

Comment: If the complete JAR B is inside JAR A (as opposed to the contents of JAR B inside JAR A directly) then you would need a custom classloader to find classes within it. There is no built-in support for nested JARs.